# Why is Php not Printing html within Php Brackets

Tags: php, html

I have code that looks like this

```
<?php 
$totalpurchase = 23;
if(empty($totalpurchase)){?>

<div class="error">You much buy something before you can leave</div>

<?php}else{?>

<div class="error">You can leave now.Thank you</div>
<?php}?>
```

I don't know why those divs don't print out to the screen. When I was using PHP version 5.6 I did not experience this. Now I am using Php version 7, and I noticed it. What would have caused such thing to happen?

Comment: This is the only code on the page? Perhaps you are getting a fatal error..

Comment: You need a space or a new line after `<?php`. But afaik this did not change from PHP5 to PHP7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$totalpurchase = 23;
if(!empty($totalpurchase)) { 
  ?>

<div class="error">You much buy something before you can leave</div>

<?php 
  }else
 { 
 ?> 
<div class="error">You can leave now.Thank you</div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Give  the space between  tags: https://eval.in/871798

For Your Reference Read This: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Answers should have explanations. The code should have given one of the messages regardless of the conditional.

Comment: Write now I am using cellphone, So Wait I will update it.

Comment: Thank you. I added the space and everything is working fine now. I thought they said in Php, the space doesn't matter example "elseif" and "else if" are still the same. It is really strange.